# Should I use Greensock entirely instead of JQuery?

Tags: jquery, gsap

I am fully aware of the performance gain when I use Greensock. I want to use it. However, I am confused because I often use

1) JQuery if and else statements

2) JQuery addClass, toggleClass, removeClass

3) JQuery on Click

4) JQuery on Scroll

Can I do all this with Greensock or do I use both in combination? I searched but didnt find any answers online.

I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: What are the jquery if/else statements?  Isn't that just native Javascript?

Comment: @msturdy actually yes. Im just very confused and unsure. I have alot of jquery code Ive written which I want to convert to greensock

Comment: If you're talking about GSAP it only replaces jQuery.animate (and it also ships as a jQuery plugin.)

Comment: Greensock isn't a full jQuery replacement.. it's mainly to replace the animations.  You should try to use it as a jQuery plugin and continue to use jQuery for your selections and DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Greensock is specifically an animation platform.  It's awesome at bascially two things: Tweening, and sequencing tweens.

Literally anything in the DOM, or any attribute can be tweened with Greensock.

But once you start getting into functionality, you're outside of Greensock's featureset.  So then the question is, what's your preferred flavor of javascript?  I use Greensock extensively with plain vanilla js to maximize speed.  But there's no reason to not use Jquery if it helps you code faster.

Keep in mind:

1) Greensock and Jquery play very nicely together.  There's no reason to not use TweenLite for your animation and if you're seeing performance gains, and Jquery for your logic.

2) It sounds like most of the functionality you're looking for is pretty basic.  You might be okay without jQuery and just using plain old .js.

There are no right and wrong directions here.  Both platforms play well with each other.  And it doesn't sound like any of them is essential for your goals.  Pick and choose from either one.

- GS / Plain JS = okay
- GS / Jquery = okay
- Jquery alone = okay

Comment: Thanks for the research on this and giving a good opinion on the libraries